# user config for app

Tags: android, xml

I want to have some user modifiable configuration for my app. Since i am new to android, I would like to know what the standard way of storing user configuration is. I am tending towards a solution with a xml file under res/xml. What would you recommend ? and are there any forseeable problems with the xml approach?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I would like to have a screen for the user to choose a config to run the app with, if that helps in deciding what the config itself should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the user defined values in sharedPreferences:
[Android Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

If you want to configure the user a lot of values you can think of saving them to sqlite database.

Comment: Don't you mean sqlite db? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db